# Gravity forms, checking for duplicate entry and redirecting to that post after once submission fails

Tags: php, forms, redirect, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form that creates a custom post. On success, I managed to redirect the user's browser to the new post.
However, when the validator fails because the user is typing the same data on the form, I would like them to be redirected to the already existing post.
I've been researching, this may be possible to achieve with the filter "gform_validation". But im not sure how the logic here would work.

Here is my approach, currently not working.

```
add_filter( 'gform_validation_1', 'custom_validation' );
function custom_validation( $validation_result ) {

    $form = $validation_result["form"];
    $entry = $_POST["input_21"];

    if($entry != null ){
        // Do nothing
    }
    else{
        $validation_result["is_valid"] = false;
        header("Location: http://www.anypage.com"); /* Redirect browser to some page */
    }
    $validation_result["form"] = $form;
    return $validation_result;
};
```

Currently when the form fails, it keeps redirecting to the homepage.
I'll appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Im using a Gravity Form to enable users to create a custom type post. Is working great, however the problem I want to tap into is that if the same user fills the form again with the exact same values, he gets redirected to the site's homepage. I dont want that. I would like to use 'gform_validation' filter to check if the same info is already available on the DB and redirect the user to the post that he created originally.

Comment: Seems like the gform_is_duplicate filter would help to achieve this betterish, but still no luck on finding a good resource on how this would work. Will keep posting any progress I may achieve.